# link user account to multiple billing entities

Tags: sql, coldfusion

I have a table with user info and a column call CompanyBillingID which links this account to a billing entity in another table.  I would like to modify this to have this user account be able to link to multiple billing entities.  Looking for a push in the right direction on how to do this.  Current SQL statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO EmailContacts (Name, 
                           Email, 
                           Password, 
                           Pull, 
                           StatsAccess,
                           ModifyWebAccess,
                           CompanyBillingID, 
                           Company,
                           BillingContact) 
VALUES ('#newname#', '#form.email#', '#form.password#', #form.pull#,#form.statsaccess#, #form.modifywebaccess#,#form.billingcompanyid#,'#form.company#',#form.billingcontact#)
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.
-CK

Comment: Unless you want your app to suffer SQL injection attacks, you should be **use [cfqueryparam](http://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam)**!

Comment: This also is only tangentially related to ColdFusion. It's a SQL problem, really.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a one-to-many? One customer can have multiple billing entries? Then add a CustomerID column in your billing table, and link each billing entry to one customer.

Do you want many customers to be able to hook to many company ids (many-to-many)? In other words, should two customers be able to have the same billing id? Then you need to follow Gian's advice, and put a join table in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you could create a third table that links users to billing entries, and then there can be as many of these associations as you like.